# Read route template into C# params parameter for method overriding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In a **base** class there is a virtual method who's input signature is `params object?[]? id`.
This method leverages the Entity Framework Core [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.find?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet%25601.Find)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-7.0) method which can find an entity
with any number of primary key values.

I would like to override (or [hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)) this method by reading the route template into a [prams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) parameter
when there are multiple primary keys in the [route template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httpgetattribute.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-httpgetattribute-ctor(system-string)).

I can introduce an overload in the derived class and call the base method but
the base method is still visible in the API. This is not desirable because when
a model has a [composite primary key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) an exception is thrown by calling the base method through the API.

[image]

**Below is a simplified example of the architecture**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Example.Controller;

public class Model { } // Has any number of keys

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class Base<TEntity> : ControllerBase where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext Context;

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public virtual object? Method(params object?[]? id) =>
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
}

public class Derived : Base<Model>
{
    // Overriding does not work because the signature doesn't match
    // 'Derived.Get(int, int)': no suitable method found to override
    [HttpGet("{a}/{b}")]
    public override object? Method(int a, int b) => base.Method(a, b);

    // Overloading in the derived class, passing parameters as arguments
    // to the base method works as expected
    [HttpGet("{a}/{b}/{c}")]
    public object? Method(int a, int b, int c) => base.Method(a, b, c);
}
```

**Questions**

- Is there some way to read `"{a}/{b}/{c}"` directly into the base method parameter `id`?
- Is there an alternate way to have a `HttpGet` method with a variable number of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into using so called slug parameters:

> Asterisk `*` or double asterisk `**`:
>
> - Can be used as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI.
> - Are called a catch-all parameters. For example, `blog/{**slug}`:
>   Matches any URI that starts with `blog/` and has any value following it.
>   The value following `blog/` is assigned to the slug route value.

So you can treat your id as slug parameter and split the value by the `/`, though it will treat everything as `string` and will not verify that correct amount of parameters is passed, you will need to do that manually.

Possibly something could be achieved with [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0), but personally I would not be introducing such class in the first place, or trying to reuse it via inheritance for composite PK cases (so just do not inherit the `Base<TEntity>` or introduce another level of inheritance were base one will just contain the methods as protected helper ones). I would argue that [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) should not conflict with [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) one and overgeneralization leading to overcomplication is not a good thing.

Read more:

- [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates)

Comment: Using the `{**slug}` parameter resulted in a less than desirable method in my first attempt, **but it worked** and showed me I probably shouldn't do that (like you mentioned in you answer).  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkDavich was glad to help! Maybe there is some way to achieve the desired result in more convenient way (with keeping the hierarchy from OP) which I can't think of ATM but I still would argue they  better left for academic/research purposes =)